# Displaying pdf files from google drive

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive, flysystem-google-drive

I am displaying pdf files from my google drive on my webpage. I did it by showing an Iframe with this link:

`https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id={FILE_ID}`

This worked well for a while. But suddenly the file is just downloading instead of being shown in the IFrame. I read about maybe there is some QUOTA from google that prevents from using the `export=view` for too many users. I couldn't find any information on that. Does anyone know if they just changed their file management and I need to change my links? Or if having a pro plan with google drive fixes this issue?

I struggle to find any information on this. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's explained here:
https://gist.github.com/tzmartin/1cf85dc3d975f94cfddc04bc0dd399be

*src="https://docs.google.com/viewer?srcid=**[YOUR_FILE_ID]**&pid=explorer&efh=false&a=v&chrome=false&embedded=true"*

Example:

```html
<html>
<body>
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/viewer?srcid=1fmvVwtP6LmI9nPPtp-962rUmIKfdSANY&pid=explorer&efh=false&a=v&chrome=false&embedded=true" width="580px" height="480px"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Tested it on Edge (Version 120.0.2210.133) and Chrome (Version 120.0.6099.224)

Comment: Oh thanks! I didn't find this.